# json clone data to alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, json

loading JSON data and presenting phone number working fine but calling external function the data cut part of the number

the following JSON code:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "GET",
    data: {No: val },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    error: function () {
        alert('error');
        } ,
    onFailure: function () {
        alert('Fail');
    } ,
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result.sites,function(index,dat){
            var site_phone='<a href="#" onClick="dialto('+dat.telephone+')"><img src="phone.png" alt="dial" /></a>'
            $("#phone").append(

                    '<div style=" height:50px;width:400px;direction:ltr;">'+
                        site_phone+
                        '<h2>'+dat.telephone+'</h2>'+
                    '</div>'
            );
        }); 
    }
})
function dialto(telephone)
{       
        alert(telephone);
        window.open('tel:'+telephone+'', '_system');
}
```

dat.telephone presenting the right number 077-123456
alert(telephone) presenting -123456

any idea?

Comment: The string isn't quoted.  I would expect it to show `-123393` as that is 77 - 123456.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
var site_phone='<a href="#" onClick="dialto(\''+dat.telephone+'\')"><img src="phone.png" alt="dial" /></a>'
```

notice the extra `\'` basicly some how you need to send the numper as a whole this way it renders as `077-123456`